# What are the wavelet coefficients of a time series that is linear interpolated?

Tags: wavelets

I want to know the relationship between the wavelet coefficients of a time series before and after linear interpolated.

Suppose we have a time series

$x(0),x(1),x(2),\cdots$.

When this time series is linear interpolated, the result becomes

$x(0),\alpha x(0)+(1-\alpha)x(1),x(1),\alpha x(1)+(1-\alpha)x(2),\cdots$.

where $\alpha$ is a real constant.

If the detailed and approximate coefficients of $x(n)$ are $d_{j,m}$ and $a_{j,k}$, respectively, can the wavelet coefficients for the interpolated time series be written as expressions of $d_{j,k}$,$a_{j,k}$?

Any suggestion or reference would be greatly appreciated.